# ping on linux vs ping on mikrotik

Tags: linux, networking, router, network-interface

I have ubuntu server 14.04, with two network cards (LAN and WAN).

I made a masquerate for WAN card. I have internet access from a host within the Lan of router.

I do a ping to 8.8.8.8 and try to navigate opening up several videos on Youtube. I see that the response from the ping times increase up to 1300ms. If I do the same thing in a Mikrotik Router, the times are the most to 600ms.

I would like to know how I can improve those timeouts, on the Linux system. I add any configuration?, by that it seems that linux is less efficient?.

Comment: Are the packet sizes the same in both cases?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is the network between the server and the router.

Answer (score 0):

No It doesn't mean Linux is less efficient, maybe even the other way; 
because when throughput/traffic increase and there is no more room for packets, packets(ICMP packets) delay more.
So maybe the linux is even doing his job faster and allowing more youtube traffic and making your icmp packets to delay more.

And also as @Barmar(in comments) mentioned default packet size on linux is 64 but in mikrotik it is 50!

> On mikrotik you can prioritize icmp packets over other things in
>   queues! to have same delay even on high traffic.